# "Page layouts and site templates" link/page is broken

Tags: site-collection, template, site-settings

I have created a new site collection based on a template (using c#) and everything goes great with one exception. I am unable to go to 'site settings' -> 'Page layouts and site templates'. After checking the correlation id the issue is

"List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."

What list is it looking for? How can I change the list that is being pointed to?

I checked that there is a valid pagelayouts list but maybe the GUID doesn't match.

Comment: Is it a custom template or OOTB?

Comment: I dynamically create a custom template as showen here : http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-creating-sites-site-collections-custom-web-template/

Comment: I set the template type to fullportabilty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When template was applied to the site collection all page layouts received invalid content types and were pending approval. After correcting this everything works.